# Concourse pending for long time before running task

Tags: docker, artifactory, concourse

I have a Concourse Pipeline with a Task using a Docker image that is stored in our local Artifactory server. Every time I start the Pipeline it takes about 5 mins until the tasks are finally run. The log looks like this:

[image]

I assume that Concourse somehow checks for newer versions of the Docker image. Unfortunately I have no chance to debug since all the logfiles on the Concourse worker VM offer no usable information.

My Questions:

1. How can I possibly debug what's going on, when Concourse says "preparing build" and the status is "pending".
2. Is there any chance to avoid Concourse from checking for a newer version of the Docker image? I tagged the Docker image with version `latest` - might this be an issue?
3. Any further ideas how I could speed things up?

Here is the detailed configuration of my pipeline and tasks:

pipeline.yml:

```
---
resources:
- name: concourse-image
  type: docker-image
  source:
    repository: OUR_DOMAIN/subpath/concourse
    username: ...
    password: ...
    insecure_registries:
    - OUR_DOMAIN

# ...

jobs:
- name: deploy
  public: true
  plan:
  - get: concourse-image
  - task: create-manifest
    image: concourse-image
    file: concourse/tasks/create-manifest/task.yml
    params:
      # ...
```

task.yml:

```
---
platform: linux

inputs:
- name: git
- name: concourse

outputs:
  - name: deployment-manifest

run:
  path: concourse/tasks/create-and-upload-cloud-config/task.sh
```

Comment: can you check ATC, worker logs for any failures? Could be worker is not reachable or ran out of space...

Comment: Hi @MariaS - thx for your suggestion. The logfiles unveiled no useful information, but `tcpdump` gave us some insights :)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The reason for this problem was that we pulled the Docker image from an internal Docker registry, which is running on **HTTP** only. Concourse tried to pull the image using **HTTPS** and it took around 5 mins until Concourse switched to HTTP (that's what a `tcpdump` on the worker showed us).

Changing the resource configuration to the following config solved the problems:

```
resources:
- name: concourse-image
  type: docker-image
  source:
    repository: OUR_SERVER:80/subpath/concourse
    username: docker-readonly
    password: docker-readonly
    insecure_registries:
    - OUR_SERVER:80
```

So basically it was **adding the port explicitly** to the `repository` and the `insecure_registries`.